# Access VBA to Create Variable URL Link Button with Field Value

Tags: ms-access

I have hunted around but can only find Excel references that dont apply...

I am trying to create a button hyperlink with a variable element at the end which is the value inside a field on a form.

The code I have so far is...

Shell "explorer " & Chr(34) & "https://store-571ygribq9.mybigcommerce.com/admin/index.php?ToDo=printOrderInvoice&orderId=2524" & Chr(34)

This code works perfectly and there is no authentication issues when it opens the webpage.

The Number 2524 at the end of the url is the part that will change based on the value inside a form field or combo or something like that.

I am about 2 weeks into MS Access so be gentle with me.

I would massively appreciate some help with this as its driving me bonkers now. I can't get any google solution to work.

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to concatenate the required value into the code instead of the fixed value:

```
Shell "explorer " & Chr(34) & "https://store-571ygribq9.mybigcommerce.com/admin/index.php?ToDo=printOrderInvoice&orderId=" & Me!cboDataField & Chr(34)
```

Comment: Thank you for replying...
I have just tried this... "Id" is the variable field name.

Private Sub InvoicePrint_Click()
Shell "explorer " & Chr(34) & "https://store-571ygribq9.mybigcommerce.com/admin/index.php?ToDo=printOrderInvoice&orderId=" & Me!cboId & Chr(34)
End Sub

Now it says can't find the field... cboId

Comment: If your field name is `Id`, then replace `cboDataField` with `Id`.

Comment: Oh it works like a dream!!! You are a legend Sir!! Thank you ever so much. I am so not a programmer and was kinda bumbling my way through with google searches etc, but I could figure out where I was going wrong with this one. Thanks again!!